# Json Deserialize C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, format

I want to parsing this json file.

> {"features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[26.4217861898109,40.127607984644],[26.4219934821323,40.1275230229872],[26.4218810759267,40.1273800013679],[26.4216801413981,40.1274730404221],[26.4217861898109,40.127607984644]]]},"properties":{"ParselNo":"1","Alan":"340.48
>   m2","Mevkii":"-","Nitelik":"Arsa","Ada":"698","Il":"Çanakkale","Ilce":"Merkez","Pafta":"16","Mahalle":"Barbaros"}}],"type":"FeatureCollection","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}}

I try this code:

```
string fileName = file.FileName;
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

string s1 = Convert.ToString(stuff.features.Count);
string s2 = stuff.properties.ParselNo;
MessageBox.Show(s1);
MessageBox.Show(s2);
```

s1 is working but s2 give error. How can I fix it?

I want to get it like this:

```
Coordinates[] coordinates = [(26.xx, 40.xx), (26.xx,40.xx) ... ]
ParselNo = 1
Alan = 340.48
Nitelik = Arsa
Ada = 698
İl = Çanakkale
İlçe = Merkez
Pafta = 16
dat_name = EPSG:4326
```

what can i do?

Comment: `but s2 give error` no it doesn't.  I see no error in your question.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `json` you provided features are  `List<Feature>` so you cannot access a property of list like `stuff.features.properties.ParselNo` it should be

`stuff.features[0].properties.ParselNo`

i used `features[0]` because it will get the first `feature` from the list and `features.Count` will return the number of `features` in `list`  you can use http://json2csharp.com/ to check your `json`

**Edit**

and about your second question it should be like this

```
List<List<double>> s2 =stuff.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0].ToObject<List<List<double>>>();
var firstcordinates = s2[0];
```

it will get the coordinates from array and `s2[0]` will get first coordinates from list

Comment: Hi. stuff.features[0].properties.ParselNo is working. Thank you. But I'm not work this: stuff.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];

Answer (score 2):

If you properly format your json as below i believe

```
 stuff.features.properties.ParselNo;
```

should get the the Parse1No

```
  {  
   "features":[  
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[  
               [  
                  [  
                     26.4217861898109,
                     40.127607984644
                  ],
                  [  
                     26.4219934821323,
                     40.1275230229872
                  ],
                  [  
                     26.4218810759267,
                     40.1273800013679
                  ],
                  [  
                     26.4216801413981,
                     40.1274730404221
                  ],
                  [  
                     26.4217861898109,
                     40.127607984644
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         },
         "properties":{  
            "ParselNo":"1",
            "Alan":"340.48 m2",
            "Mevkii":"-",
            "Nitelik":"Arsa",
            "Ada":"698",
            "Il":"Çanakkale",
            "Ilce":"Merkez",
            "Pafta":"16",
            "Mahalle":"Barbaros"
         }
      }
   ],
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "crs":{  
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{  
         "name":"EPSG:4326"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you use and editor that knows how to reformat your text, questions like this can almost answer themselves.  VisualStudio has a JSON viewer that can create a tree view, and Notepad++ (free) can reformat it for you.

Comment: I have failed :(

Answer (score 0):

I try this:

```
 string s2 = stuff.features.properties.ParselNo;
 MessageBox.Show(s2);
```

give this error:
[Error...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u6P9.png)

Answer (score 0):

This code work: stuff.features[0].properties.ParselNo
But don't this: stuff.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];

I don't understand it :(
[Error code..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATjEN.png)